# Os.walk only extracting a few files and no text information

Tags: os.walk

Stack Overflow community! I'm trying to write some code to extract all .txt files from a folder in my files directory, using os.walk. But it isn't working for some reason - it isn't extracting any text because "the file doesn't exist" and os.walk is only extracting 8 files.

```
#import data
import os
rootDir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/HighLowQualityCounseling/transcripts'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)     
for fname in fileList:
    print('\t%s' % fname)
for fname in fileList:
  myfile = open(fname, "rt")
  contents = myfile.read()         
  myfile.close()                   
  print(contents) ###
```

How should I go about fixing this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't that only get a list of the files in that directory, and not the path too?

Answer (score 0):

`fname` doesn’t have the full file name. You need to add the path back on.

```
os.path.join(dirName, fName)
```